# How to test HTTP Only Cookie Set using Axios

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, axios, jwt

To preface this, I am using Express, and Jest + Axios to do E2E tests.

I have a test suite, where I am creating a user, and I would like the test to assert that the HTTP-ONLY cookie was set during the process.

I know these HTTP-ONLY cookies are not supposed to be read by the browser, however I am wondering if there is any easy way to test this.

Here is some pseudocode of my current flow.

```
it('Should Create a User', async () => {
  const account = {
    username: faker.internet.userName(),
    password: faker.internet.password(),
  };
  const axiosRes = await axios.post(`/auth/create`, account);
  const user = await userRepository.getByName(account.username);
  expect(user.username).toEqual(account.username);

  // What I would like to test
  expect(axiosRes.cookie('jwtToken').isSet());
});
```

Edit: Is my best route to set the token in a header?

Comment: An httponly cookie is *only* accessible by the browser. It is not accessible by javascript.

Comment: What suggestion would you recommend for testing this? Could i also set the jwtToken in the headers, so I can easily assert it in my tests?

That seems a bit unsafe.

Comment: I honestly don't know that you can test this without manually checking the web inspector's cookie tab or using a traffic interceptor of some kind. Tokens are often passed through the `Authorization` header, so I suppose that is an option if you want to make that change.